# Проблемы с проектированием базы данных на основе ORM

Tags: ооп, orm, проектирование, kohana, php

Добрый день.

Сначала перечисляю сущности.
`sуstems` - некие системы.
`preferences` - некоторые настройки, сокращенно `pref`

pref имеет разные типы, например настройки кеша (cache) и тамаута (timeout).
Таким образом pref можно записывать в одну таблицу с полями `id, value, type` или в две разные таблицы - `prefcache и preftimeout` с той же структурой. Идем дальше.

Поля таблицы `system - id, name.`
Осуществляется связь многие ко многим через таблицу `prefs_systems` с полями: `id_system, id_pref, type` (можно вынести сюда в случае отдельных таблиц `prefcache` и `preftimeout`.

И вот зачем две таблицы `pref`, я хочу на каждую делать свой ORM, т.е. есть базовый
`ORM_Pref extends ORM` и от него наследуются `ORM_Prefcache` и `ORM_Preftimeot`. Каждый работает со своей таблицей, а общие настройки в базовом классе.

В этом случае в каждой ORM прописываются связи `$_has_many`. В случае ORM `pref` все очевидно, по одной записи связей `$_has_many к ORM_System`. В случае с описанием `ORM_System` получается такая конструкция (додумался пока писал).

```
 protected $_has_many = array(
    'prefcache' => array(
        'model'       => 'orm_prefcache',
        'foreign_key' => 'id_system',
        'through'     => 'prefs_systems',
        'far_key'     => 'id_pref',
    ),
    'preftimeot'  => array(
        'model'       => 'orm_preftimeout',
        'foreign_key' => 'id_system',
        'through'     => 'prefs_systems',
        'far_key'     => 'id_pref',
    ),
);
```

Вопросы:

1. Почему редактор съел почти все символы нижнего подчеркивания?
2. Нормально ли я придумал структуру?
3. Могу ли я базовый класс ORM_Pref объявить абстрактным (т.к. у него нет привязанной таблицы и его не надо создавать) ?
4. Можно ли как-то улучшить мою структуру? Если все выше правильно, то при добавления нового типа настроек я должен буду прописать связь в ORM_System, это не удобно.

Comment: Первый вопрос отменяется, это в пред просмотре были съедены _

Comment: я вообще во всем это не разбираюсь, но мне интересно, это в пхп такая хорошая практика проектировать бд и их делать сразу средствами пхп, а не в редакторе мускла?

Comment: Gorets, тут речь идет про ORM, почитайте что это такое. Таблицы я конечно создаю в mysql, а ORM для описания моделей этих таблиц и связей между ними, уже в коде.

Comment: В любом случае я закодил эту структуру и она работает. Вопрос в том можно ли ее улучшить.

Comment: а ОРМ коханы не умеет сама создавать таблицы?

Comment: Нет, она требует созданной таблицы иначе ошибка.
Речь вообще не об этом. :)

Answer (score 1):

хорошо в таком случае использовать orm-библиотеки (напр. Doctrine). Можно создать схему в mysql workbench, форвард-инжинирингом создать БД и при помощи комманды doctrine сгенерировать сущности

Comment: *рисуем остаток совы*